# ErrorReporting.getInstance() not working

Tags: android, acra

I'm using ACRA 4.8.5. And I want to save crash logs into the internal memory instead of sending it, but everytime I use this code, `ErrorReporter.getInstance().setReportSender(new LocalReportSender(this));`this code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got that code from, but this isn't how it is supposed to work.

If you want to use a custom `ReportSender`, you have to configure a custom `ReportSenderFactory` class in your annotation (or in the ConfigurationBuilder).

Comment: i get my code from here: https://acra.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/4.3.0b2/org/acra/ErrorReporter.html. but the ACRA version is 4.3.0 and i'm using 4.8.5.

Comment: there is a big difference between 4.3 and 4.8. You'd better check the current docs at https://github.com/ACRA/acra